# how to sort files in a directory based on the contents of the files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to programming, currently I am trying to sort out '.text' files in a directory based on the contents of each files.

The contents of the files would have random numbers in them such `'a.text' = 5`, and `'b.text' = 3`. I wish to sort the files in the directory in ascending order based on the value of its contents using Python.

I tried looking at `sorted()` and `sort()` but most of what I found is only to sort the value inside the files. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Are the values all integers or floats? Is there more than one value in any file?

Comment: You can't sort files in a directory. It's system specific. The OS will sort them by name, date, type etc.

Comment: Do you mean how it appears in the explorer window?

Comment: Do you mean you have something like a `list` of filenames in Python and you want to sort the `list` based upon the contents of the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a function that can be used as a `key` for `sort`/`sorted`.

Here we open it, read the content and convert it to a `float`. This assumes that there is only one number in each file (and nothing else) and that it can be converted to a `float`. This key function is called exactly once for each input record (so no unnecessary file reads).

```
def get_content(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return float(f.read())

files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"]
sorted(files, key=get_content)
# ['b.txt', 'a.txt']
```

With two files like this:

```
a.txt
10

b.txt
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Building upon @Graipher's answer, but using pythons `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path

files = ["a.txt", "b.txt"]
sorted(files, key=lambda f: float(Path(f).read_text()))
# ['b.txt', 'a.txt']
```